# GLib: g_source_remove() not stopping timeout callbacks on non-default GMainContext

Tags: glib

I am using this function to add a timeout callback (repeated) to a specific `GMainContext`.

```
guint GstThreadHelper::timeoutAdd(guint delay, GSourceFunc function, gpointer data) {
    // See https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/main-contexts.html.en#implicit-use-of-the-global-default-main-context
    // It is important that all thread functions we invoke don't implicitly decide a maincontext.
    // We must manually provide one.
    GSource *source = NULL;
    guint id;

    source = g_timeout_source_new(delay);
    g_source_set_callback (source, function, data, NULL);
    id = g_source_attach (source, priv->mainContext);
    g_source_unref (source);

    return id;
}
```

Later, I use the returned `id` to cancel the callback.

```
void GstThreadHelper::timeoutRemove(guint id) {
    g_source_remove(id);
}
```

However, the callback still gets called. Here is my callback.

```
static gboolean position_update (gpointer user_data)
{
    Player::PrivateData* priv = (Player::PrivateData*)user_data;
    gint64 pos = 0;

    if (gst_element_query_position (priv->playbin, GST_FORMAT_TIME, &pos)) {
        pos = pos / 1000000;
        priv->callback->PositionChanged(pos);
    }

    // Call me again
    return TRUE;
}
```

I understand I am returning `TRUE`, but my understanding is that it still should be stopped. If I cancel callbacks by returning `FALSE`, I wouldn't bother with the `g_source_remove` call.

Why doesn't `g_source_remove` stop my callback from being raised?

**EDIT**

If I replace my `timeoutAdd` method with this...

```
guint GstThreadHelper::timeoutAdd(guint delay, GSourceFunc function, gpointer data) {
    return g_timeout_add(delay, function, data);
}
```

...it works. However, I can't use this, because it doesn't trigger the callbacks on a specific `GMainContext`, as opposed to the default global `GMainContext`.

**EDIT2**

I copied the default source for `g_timeout_add_seconds_full` into my function, and it worked.

However, the moment I changed `g_source_attach` to use my private `GMainContext`, it failed.

The issue is something to do with calling `g_source_remove` for timeouts added on non-default `GMainContext`s.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `g_source_remove` operates under the assumption that you are using the global/default `GMainContext`, which in this case, I am not.

I don't remember reading this in the docs.

Anyways, Here is the solution.

```
void GstThreadHelper::timeoutRemove(guint id) {
    GSource* source = g_main_context_find_source_by_id(priv->mainContext, id);
    if (source)
        g_source_destroy (source);
}
```

This is essentially what `g_source_remove` is doing, but instead using our private `GMainContext`.

Comment: You got it. This is mentioned in the documentation for `g_source_remove()`: “Removes the source with the given id from the default main context.” but I will push a change to GLib to clarify this. Using `g_source_destroy()` (and passing the `GSource*` pointer around, with a reference held to it; rather than passing the `guint` tag around) is correct.